# How to store values from a while loop to a list as a property in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to add each session Id that is retrieved from a **Loop Controller** to a list and assign it to a property for use in the following thread group? Below I used a couple of **Dummy Sampler** to explain my requirement.

I had 3 users stored in a list to retrieve 3 session ids in the **setUp Thread Group**.

JSR223 PreProcessor

```
List usernames = Arrays.asList('Peter', 'Alex', 'Mary');
props.put('accounts', usernames);
```

I was able to read a username from this property to get a session id in the response accordingly per iteration in the **Loop Controller**.

```
"sessionId": "this_is_my_session_id-${__groovy(props.get('accounts').get(${__jm__LoopController__idx} % 3),)}-${__jm__LoopController__idx} "
```

[image]

I parsed the 3 session ids out by a **JSR223 PostProcessor**

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def response = jsonSlurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
def json = JsonOutput.toJson(response.sessionId)
def sessionId = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
log.info('The session id is:' + sessionId)

ArrayList<String> sessionIds = new ArrayList<String>();
props.put("sessionIds", sessionIds.add(sessionId))
```

I needed to add these 3 session ids to a list and assign it to a property so that I can use one session id inside the property per VU/thread in the following **Thread Group**. But it didn't work as expected. It threw error saying *No such property: sessionIds*

```
 ${__groovy(props.get(sessionIds).get(${__jm__UseSession__idx} % 3),)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what do you "expect"

Most probably the problem is here:

```
props.put("sessionIds", sessionIds.add(sessionId))
```

[Collection.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-) function returns a [boolean](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_booleans.asp) value so it puts `true` to the `sessionIds` property instead of the real value of the ArrayList.

So I believe you need to change it to something like:

```
sessionIds.add(sessionId)
props.put("sessionIds", sessionIds)
```

if you're going to run the JSR223 Test Element in the loop you can also reconsider the way you're initializing the `sessionIds` and implement the following logic:

1. If `sessionIds` property exists - read its value
2. If it doesn't exist - create a new ArrayList

Something like:

```
ArrayList<String> sessionIds = props.get("sessionIds") ?: new ArrayList<String>()
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)